# Internet Explorer prependTo displaying differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have the following HTML code:-

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li class="a">item 1</li>
    <li class="a">item 2</li>
    <li class="b">item 3</li>
    <li class="b">item 4</li>
</ul>
```

And the following script:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function() {
            $("#list1 li:last").prependTo("#list1 li:first");

    });
</script>
```

The intended display is:-

[image: Intended Display]

But on IE I'm seeing:-

[image: IE]

I'm using jQuery 1.10.2.

Any clues?

Comment: You add a `li` inside another `li`, which results in an invalid document structure. Only `ul` elements can have `li` elements as children. It's no wonder that browsers render the invalid(!) result differently. Maybe you intended to prepend the `li` to the `ul` element? Or *insert* it *before* the first `li` element? If you also  explain to us what you are trying to achieve with the code, we would be able to help you. But without an explanation, we can only guess (which usually does not produce useful results).

Comment: Or, maybe he wants nested lists, which means he must insert a ul element first.

Comment: `$("#list1 li:last").prependTo("#list1");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to move the last `li` to the first position, that means you need to prepend it to the `ul` element not to the first li

```
$("#list1 li:last").prependTo("#list1");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a2AwL/)

which is the same as inserting it before the first element using `insertBefore('#list1 li:first')`

Why the display varies in browsers? Because you create an invalid html markup by appending an `li` to another `li`, `li` should be added to a `ul` or `ol` element

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put the last `li` to the first position before the first `li`, try to use [insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) instead:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#list1 li:last").insertBefore("#list1 li:first");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BQM9R/)

or you can use [prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) which has the same effect:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#list1 li:last").prependTo("#list1");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dmcmE/)